# WMI parsing not expected result

Tags: powershell, wmi

I wrote a script to get the IP address of a remote machine, this is working as intended.  The problem is I'm trying to only show the IPv4 address and not the IPv6 address so I created some logic but its not working, what am I doing wrong here?

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName remoteserver Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | ? {
  $_.IPAddress -ne $null -and $_.IPAddress -ne 'fe80*'
} | select -ExpandProperty IPAddress
```

Comment: $_.IPAddress is an array which in some cases would contain and IPv4 and IPv6 address. What output are you looking for? all adapters that are not configured with ipv6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the below, you can see `IPAddress` is a property of `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` object, but it's actually an object array:

```powershell
DHCPEnabled      : False
IPAddress        : {192.168.3.1, fe80::8c4a:cfd3:6c30:5695}
DefaultIPGateway :
DNSDomain        :
ServiceName      : VMnetAdapter
Description      : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
Index            : 5

PS> ((Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select ipaddress ).ipaddress).gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

This means that you need to iterate over the array with a foreach `%` to extract the value you want:

```powershell
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | ? { $_.IPAddress -ne $null} | % { $_.ipaddress -inotlike 'fe80*' }
```

Also note I've changed the comparison from `-ne` to `-inotlike`. `-ne` matches exactly, whereas you can use the wildcard `*` in a `-like` comparison

Answer (score 1):

You could also expand the `IPAddress` property before filtering:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName remoteserver Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
  select -ExpandProperty IPAddress |
  ? { $_ -ne $null -and $_ -notlike 'fe80*' }
```